# Problem with unserializing a PHP class and with gzinflate

Tags: php, class, serialization, gzip

I am trying to serialize a class (User) and pass it as a GET variable to the next page.

Here is my test code:

```
$usr->getByLoginPass($db,"perf@stud.de","a32636ba1c7875b19c6f32121078c2da0be6f857");
$serial = $usr->serialize();
$handle = fopen("http://localhost/newClassSite/utests/userSerializationTest.php?data=$serial", "rb");
$contents = "";
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
if(strpos($contents,"Perfect") === false) {
    echo"$contents<br>";
    echo"Problem with serialization testUser.test:16" . $usr->getLastError() . "<br>";
}
```

Here is the code in userSerializationTest.php:

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
echo"5: $data<br>";
include('../user.inc');
$usr = new User();
$usr->deserialize($data);
$usr->printUser();
```

Here is the code within the class:

```
public function serialize() {
    $serial = serialize($this);
    $df = gzdeflate($serial);
    $b64 = base64_encode($df);
    $ue = urlencode($b64);
    echo "<font face='Courier New'>1: $serial<br><br>2: $df<br><br>3: $b64<br><br>4: $ue<hr><br>";
    return($ue);
}

public function deserialize($data) {
    $ud = urldecode($data);
    $u64 = base64_decode($ud);
    $gf = gzinflate($u64);
    $us = unserialize($gf);
    echo"6: $ud<br><br>7: $u64<br><br>8: $gf<br><br>9: $us<hr><br>";
}
```

### And here is the output:

1: O:4:"User":9:{s:12:"UseruserID";s:1:"9";s:15:"UserstudentID";s:3:"007";s:11:"Useremail";s:12:"perf@stud.de";s:10:"Usersha1";s:40:"a32636ba1c7875b19c6f32121078c2da0be6f857";s:11:"Userfname";s:7:"Perfect";s:11:"Userlname";s:7:"Student";s:12:"Userstatus";s:2:"OK";s:17:"UsermiddleNames";s:0:"";s:15:"UserlastError";s:0:"";}

2: ]MÂ „=0@[hŸº0&ÖÄxÊOlÒVte¼»”†ÆºðÍ0o †ÐÝi‹ ‚·Bm¦ófËé€vªâ^$ÍùQéÁÏrc $t/Ú.¢÷ÒÖì§+[¥#ÃKÎC‰äˆŒ²Œ5‚H^ò¢!•d&£„ÌKI•Àf¦,þ™Aô1”º†9Zúµ¡û1ÜæÚ©Wz‹ð£›X@õ9Š<‰}«T§/!":BÍõGtÂù£µO»¨Ÿ/

3: XZBNDsIgFIQ9CwcwQFtonxsXujAm1sR4AMpPbNJWA3RlvLuUhsa6gfDNMG+ghhzQ3WmLoIK3A0IBbabzZgzL6YB2gQGq4l4kzflR6cHPcgYIYx4NJBl0L9ouopD30tbspytbpSPDS85DkInkgYiMsow1gkhe8qIhlWQmo4QSzEtJlcCNZqYs/gaZQfQxlAO6hjla+rWh+zHc5tqpV3qL8KObWED1OYo8iX2rVKcvISI6Qs31R3TC+aO1T7uony8=

4: XZBNDsIgFIQ9CwcwQFtonxsXujAm1sR4AMpPbNJWA3RlvLuUhsa6gfDNMG%2BghhzQ3WmLoIK3A0IBbabzZgzL6YB2gQGq4l4kzflR6cHPcgYIYx4NJBl0L9ouopD30tbspytbpSPDS85DkInkgYiMsow1gkhe8qIhlWQmo4QSzEtJlcCNZqYs%2FgaZQfQxlAO6hjla%2BrWh%2BzHc5tqpV3qL8KObWED1OYo8iX2rVKcvISI6Qs31R3TC%2BaO1T7uony8%3D

5: XZBNDsIgFIQ9CwcwQFtonxsXujAm1sR4AMpPbNJWA3RlvLuUhsa6gfDNMG+ghhzQ3WmLoIK3A0IBbabzZgzL6YB2gQGq4l4kzflR6cHPcgYIYx4NJBl0L9ouopD30tbspytbpSPDS85DkInkgYiMsow1gkhe8qIhlWQmo4QSzEtJlcCNZqYs/gaZQfQxlAO6hjla+rWh+zHc5tqpV3qL8KObWED1OYo8iX2rVKcvISI6Qs31R3TC+aO1T7uony8=

Warning: gzinflate() [function.gzinflate]: data error in C:\wamp\www\newClassSite\user.inc on line 117
6: XZBNDsIgFIQ9CwcwQFtonxsXujAm1sR4AMpPbNJWA3RlvLuUhsa6gfDNMG ghhzQ3WmLoIK3A0IBbabzZgzL6YB2gQGq4l4kzflR6cHPcgYIYx4NJBl0L9ouopD30tbspytbpSPDS85DkInkgYiMsow1gkhe8qIhlWQmo4QSzEtJlcCNZqYs/gaZQfQxlAO6hjla rWh zHc5tqpV3qL8KObWED1OYo8iX2rVKcvISI6Qs31R3TC aO1T7uony8=

7: ]MÂ „=0@[hŸº0&ÖÄxÊOlÒVte¼»”†ÆºðÍ0h!‡47Zbè ­ÀÐ€[i¼Ùƒ2ú`@j¸—‰3~TzpsÜ‚ÇƒI]ö‹¨¤=ôµ»)ÊÖéHðÒóä"y b#,£`’¼¨ˆeY ¨á³Òep#Y©‹?¦P}eî¡ŽV«ZÇs›j¥]ê/ÂŽmaÔæ(ò%ö­Rœ¼„ˆé7ÕÓ   £µO»¨Ÿ/

8:

9:

User: 
ID: -1 
sID: 
email: 
pass: 
fname: 
lname: 
status: 
middle:

I would like the fields to be filled in the end.
Why is gzinflate failing?
What am I missing here?

Comment: Why not simply store it in the session array?

Comment: You really shouldn't do that. One can easily fake a user object once the class content is known.

Comment: Surely, this is not secure.
At this point I just want to get it to work so that I can pass objects.

Comment: WOW! I am good with perversions myself but you beat me with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `urldecode()` in your `deserialize()` function. PHP's already taken care of all that when it was building the $_GET array. This is most likely the problem - you're double decoding the data, and by random chance, some of the gzdata has character sequences that end up looking like legitimate urlencoded data.

As well, why are you using the `<font>` tag to output your debug data? Use `<pre>`. it's intended to output text in a fixed-width font.

Comment: Great, I am almost there ;)
Removing urldecode gave me the correct data again.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to restore the object.
I have the following:
`code
    public function deserialize($data) {
        $u64 = base64_decode($data);
        $gf = gzinflate($u64);
        unserialize($gf);
        echo"6: $u64<br><br>7: $gf<hr><br>";
    }
    function __sleep() {
        echo "<h3>__sleep()</h3>";
        return($this);
    }
    function __wakeup() {
        echo "<h3>__wakeup()</h3>";
    }
`

Comment: Remember that query parameters are usually length limited. You shouldn't be passing a serialized object via query - you have no idea how big it would be and some of it could be silently chopped off. As well, passing session data like that leaves it in the server's access logs and any referer logs elsewhere. Huge security risk. But if you insist on doing this, then strip the code down as much as possible. skip the gzip/urleconding and try passing just the plain serialized text.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the data in 3 and 6. They are not the same!

What happened is that the + character serves as a space in an URL and so the "+" get's decoded as " " between 5 and 6 (where I guess 5 is the Raw $_GET data and shows that it has already been decoded)